# Apache htaccess-redirect based on logged in user

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website with a subdirectory that's restricted to registered users. In that subdirectory, I have subfolders for every user. Now, after logging in, the user should be redirected to her/his folder automatically.
I'm trying to solve this with an htaccess-file that currently looks like this:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile    /path/to/my/site/htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/users/.+/
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.+)
Redirect (.*) /users/%1/$1 [L]
```

This is based on information I found on the web - with little success, unfortunately.

What should happen is:

-> User calls www.myserver.com/users/
-> Apache asks for username and password (e.g. jondoe - 1234)
-> User enters username and password
-> User is redirected to her/his subdirectory (like  www.myserver.com/users/jondoe/)

The password-part is working - but the redirection is not…

I'm (obviously) confused ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Instead of using Redirect, I needed to do the following:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /users/%1/$1 [L,R=302]
```

The `R=302` is the indication for a redirect.